# Proof that the following is open,closed and/or bounded: $A= \left \{ (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 \leq 1 \right \}$

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I'm trying to proof that the following set is open/closed, bounded/unbounded and compact.

$$A= \left \{ (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 \leq 1  \right \}$$

I'm not used to handling two elements x,y in the proofs, just an x. For example, to proof and open set I'm used to pick a point of the set and then see if the epsilon ball describes whether if the definition of interior points defines an open set of the form $\forall x,y \in A , \exists \varepsilon>0 : B_{\varepsilon}(x,y) \in A$ will this be correct?.

It can be done with the definitions of each set (open/closed, bounded) or if there's an intuitive way to figure it out?. Thank you.

Comment: There are some details wrong, although the basic idea is correct. Indeed, it is necessary to consider a point in the set and study what its behaviour with respect to different balls is. However, it an element in this set is a pair $(x,y)$, so one should write $(x?y)\in A$. Then, a ball $B_\epsilon(x,y)$ might be contained in $A$, but never in $A$, i.e. $B_\epsilon(x,y)\subset A$. One will realise that is not always the case, depending on the point $(x,y)$. I cannot give more details right now for the analytical proof, but it should not be hard to see intuitively that this set is...

Comment: Do you already know that quadratic functions are continuous?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Indeed. but the analytical proof is what I'm interested. For the sets

Comment: @Dog_69 Thank you very much for your comments. I think I get more the point.

Comment: Then use the fact that preimages of closed subsets under continuous functions are again closed.